Change YoloV8 Segmentation Color
I am new to YoloV8 training tasks and would like to understand how I can change the colors of a segmentation performed by the model.
If anyone has some code examples and can share them, please.
Any help to guide me will be greatly appreciated.

As far as I know, no direct tool exists to change the result plot colors in Ultralytics. You can either copy the Ultralytics git repository and manually adjust the colors in this file https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/utils/plotting.py (hexs variable) or create your own plotting function.
